# Finding original price of Tea per kg

Tags: quadratics, percentages

A reduction of $ 2 per kg enables a man to purchase 2 kg more tea for

$8. Find original price of tea per kg

**Attempt**

Let price be $x per kg of tea .So let man buys 10 kg of tea .So total cost is 10x.

Now new price is  x-2 per kg so man buys 12 kg of tea
So total cost is 12(x-2)

So 12(x-2)=8 gives x =32/12. But textbook states answer as x=4. Can someone explain this

Thanks

Comment: Where did you come up with the assumption that the man buys 10 kg of tea?

Comment: i assumed on my own.Does it matter here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $x$ be the initial price per kg of tea and $n$ the initial number of kg you could have with $8$ dollars.
Then you have
$$
nx=8 \tag1
$$ and
$$
(n+2)(x-2)=nx \tag2
$$ Expanding $(2)$ gives
$$
nx-2n+2x-4=nx
$$ or
$$
x-n=2 \tag3
$$ then, using $(1)$, we get
$$
x-\frac8x=2 \tag4
$$ or

> $$
> x^2-2x-8=0 \tag5
> $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: sure thanks .You could have even finished your answer by equation 2 only

Comment: @JPG Thanks! How?

Comment: I could have taken from there, that is why i am saying